General question about fast paced transactions
I'm just curious, what's the fastest pace you guys were able to send transactions programmatically on the blockchain (SOLANA)? (any rpc), I am able to send decently fast transactions with my code (50-100 transactions per second) but I was thinking what could improve it (my rpc handles up to 250rps)... is it because im running it with typescript and not rust? could it be my pc specs (I doubt it is I got a decent cpu gpu and ram) or is it the latency from my location to the rpc endpoint .. anyways let me know if you guys were able to nail it faster and if you did what's the approach

Rust vs Typescript won't really make a difference, since the network call overhead is likely the biggest wait.
If you really want to send a lot of transactions to the network, you may want to use a TPU client, which sends transactions directly to the leader rather than going through RPC. There's a repository that uses it at https://github.com/joncinque/solana-tpu-client-test
You can also look at bench-tps, which is the typical tool used for stress testing a network, where you should be able to land thousands of transactions per second: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/bench-tps
